# Why are these two conclusions equivalent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here is a theorem:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with law $L_X$ and $L_Y$, respectively. (e.g.  $L_X(B) = P(X \in B) \text{ for every Borel set } B$). Then, $X+Y$ has law $L_X *L_Y$, where $*$ denotes the convolution. Equivalently, $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{P}(X+Y \leq c) = \displaystyle \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}(X \leq c-y) dL_Y$.

In this theorem, I do not understand the last sentence which begins with "Equivalently,..."

Why is 
$$L_X * L_Y \text{ is the law of } X+Y \tag{1}$$ 
equivalent to

$$\forall c \in \mathbb{R},\mathbb{P}(X+Y \leq c) = \displaystyle \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}(X \leq c-y) dL_Y \tag{2} $$?

Clearly, (1) implies (2), but why does (2) imply (1)? (2) only shows that $L_X * L_Y(K) = \mathbb{P}(X+Y \in K)$ for all $K$ of the form $(-\infty,c),c\in \mathbb{R}$, not for all Borel set $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that a probability measure is uniquely determined by its CDF.

More precisely, the sets of the form $(-\infty, c]$ form a family of sets that generate the Borel-sima-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ and that is closed under finite intersections. By Dynkin's theorem a probability measure on the Borel-sigma-algebra is uniquely determined by its values on this family of sets.